# Преданный кем-то и преданный кому-то

Tags: глаголы, управление

Это, скорее, наблюдение, нежели вопрос. Интересно, что в русском языке одним и тем же словом "преданный" обозначаются диаметрально противоположные понятия — преданность и предательство. То есть может быть преданным кому-то, а можно и кем-то.

Comment: Кстати, вторый смысл достаточно прозрачен: человек отдан своему кумиру. А вот первый - не так понятен. Что кому дали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так иногда бывает со словами, пришедшими в язык в разное время и из разных языков, у них разная внутренняя семантическая мотивировка при формально одинаковом морфемном составе слов.

"Преданный кем-то"- от "ПРЕДАВАТЬ"-заимствованное из ст.-славянского, где первоначально значило "передавать"(кому-то,врагу, например), далее "сообщить" (предать огласке). В значении "предавать кого -то" - вероятно, калька с греч. παραδίδωμι -  буквально "пере-давать". В старославянском много калек с греческого, они перешли в др.-р.яз.

ПРЕДАННЫЙ в значении "верный, постоянный" - вероятно, поздняя, собственно русская калька с  нем. ERGEBEN -  от SICH ERGEBEN "посвящать себя, предаваться" от ERGEBEN "(от)давать" (стар.)

А на русской почве значения прижились, потому что легко соединялись в общеслав. корне "дать - вручить, передать из рук в руки". Предать кого - то - передать в руки врага, преданный кем-то - его передали в руки врага. Преданный кому-то -воспринимается как отглагольное прилагательное -тот, кто передал своё сердце в дар, в руки кого-то, вручил навсегда, потому ему верен. "Чему-то" предан - уже метафора.

А вообще, каждый из нас предан… Кому-то или кем-то…
 Ф. Раневская :"Есть люди, в которых живет Бог.(о тех, кто предан делу, верен служению людям) Есть люди, в которых живет дьявол.( кто предал своё дело и людей) А есть люди, в которых живут только глисты." (комментарии излишни)